# Prove: $(\cap_{i\in I} A_{i})^c=\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove: De morgan's law $$(\cap_{i\in I} A_{i})^c=\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}^c$$

Let there be 
$$x\in\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}^c\iff \exists i \in I \quad x\in A_{i}^c\iff \forall i\in I \quad x\not \in A_{i}\iff \forall i\in I \quad x\not \in \cap A_{i}\iff x\in(\cap_{i\in I} A_{i})^c$$

Is it valid?

Comment: Also, note that proving it reduces to prove the elementary two-sets case: $A^c \cup B^c = (A \cap B)^c$, because you may use it as the basis of an induction and also on the inductive step (if you set $B = A_{n+1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This step:

$$\exists i \in I \quad x\in A_{i}^c\iff \forall i\in I \quad x\not \in A_{i}$$

isn't true.

You should have:

$$\exists i \in I \quad x\in A_{i}^c\iff \exists i\in I \quad x\not \in A_{i}$$

which leads to:

$$x\in\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}^c\iff \exists i \in I \quad x\in A_{i}^c\iff \exists i\in I \quad x\not \in A_{i}\iff  x\not \in \cap A_{i}\iff x\in(\cap_{i\in I} A_{i})^c$$